# Detecting Webpack mode in JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am building a bundle of ReactJS files with Webpack.

Is it possible to detect inside of JSX files which Webpack mode is being used: `"none"`, `"development"`, or `"production"`?

For example, I would like some `console.log()` statements and global variables in development mode but not production.

Comment: I think it's pretty common to use `process.env.NODE_ENV` for this purpose.

Comment: You might want to check out the Webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I figured out the solution and posted below.

Answer (score 3):

One can build the Webpack bundle for development with:

```sh
$ npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=development
```

and for production with:

```sh
$ npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production
```

To know whether the current build is in development mode or production mode, `webpack.DefinePlugin()` should be used in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        // other directives...
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(argv.mode === 'production'),
            }),
        ],
    }
};
```

Then in the bundled JavaScript files one can have this checking:

```js
if (PRODUCTION) {
    console.log("This is a production build.");
} else {
    console.log("This is a development build.");
}
```

Note that `PRODUCTION` here will work not as a global variable, but as a template variable resolved to `true` or `false`.

Comment: do you have to import the webpack plugin into the js file where you want to see the value?

Comment: If using `eslint` you may also need `"globals": { "PRODUCTION": true }` in your `.eslintrc` file. Otherwise `eslint` may complain: `error  'PRODUCTION' is not defined  no-undef`.